# For loop in R that calculates for the group and then the components

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, subset

I have a set of data and a loop containing numerous calculations for the data set, where the individual components of the set are split into a subset and cycled through one by one.  However I need to be able to execute the same calculations across the original data set as a whole first.

For a fictional data set called `masterdata` with 3 components (column D1) and numerous variables (X2-X10) as such:

```
# masterdata
#   D1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
#   A  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#   B  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#   C  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#   B  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#   B  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#   C  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#   C  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#   A  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#   B  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#   A  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
```

A loop is in place to split off a subset for component A, perform the calculations, output the results and then repeat this for B and C:

```
Component.List = c("A", "B", "C")

for(k in 1:length(Component.List)) {        
      subdata = subset(masterdata, D1 == Component.List[k])
      # Numerous calculations performed on "subdata" within the loop
}
# End of loop
```

What I am trying to do is initially perform the same numerous calculations against the whole of `masterdata` and then start looping through the individual components.

Part of the output from the calculations is that two vectors that are created are placed into the first column of the data frames created just prior to executing the loop:

```
# Prior to the start of the loop two frames below created
Components = 3 # In this example 3 components in column D1 - "A", "B", "C"

Result.Frame.V1 = as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 200, ncol = Components))
Result.Frame.V2 = as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 200, ncol = Components))

# Loop runs and contains all of the calculations and within the calculations the last two  
# lines below place two vectors generated into the the kth columns of the frames.

Result.Frame.V1[,k] = V1.Result
Result.Frame.V2[,k] = V2.Result

# First run of the loop for "A" will place the outputs in the 1st columns 
# Second run of the loop for "B" will place the outputs in the 2nd columns, etc.
# With the expansion to also calculate against the whole group, the above data frames
# would be expanded to an extra column that would hold the result vector for the whole 
# masterdata run through the calculations
```

My initial theoretical solution is to write every calculation in the loop once for masterdata and then have the above loop, however the calculations are hundreds of lines of code!

Is it possible to incorporate into the For loop a way to calculate for the original data and then continue cycling through the components?

Comment: Why not encapsulate all the calculations into a separate function and pass the data.frames to it in sequence, `masterdata` , `ComponentA`,`ComponentB` etc

Comment: No need for a `for` loop. Split dataframe into list by component `split(masterdata, masterdata$D1)`, then use `lapply/sapply` to perform your calculation on every list entry. Use `do.call(rbind, ...)` to bind any resulting dataframes (if necessary).

Comment: Are you expecting to get a vector out of the function or a dataframe? e.i 1 row vs multiple rows?

Comment: @JonnoBourne Within the calculations there are vectors and data frames that are output from it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like [dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) would solve this elegantly, among the other options

For the whole data:

```
library(dplyr)  
masterdata %>%
  summarise(result = your_function(arg1 = X1, arg2 = X2, ...))
```

For each component, just add `group_by`

```
masterdata %>%
  group_by(D1) %>%
  summarise(result = your_function(arg1 = X1, arg2 = X2, ...))
```

Comment: What if `your_function` needs to make new columns? (`purrr::map` perhaps?)

Comment: @jakub Absolutely! Good addition to the original question.

Comment: If `your_function()` creates a single column, all you'd need would be `mutate`, no need for `purrr::map_*` (e.g., `group_by(mtcars, cyl) %>% mutate(newmu=mean(vs))`); if it creates multiple columns, you can do it perhaps with `bind_cols`.

Comment: @r2evans really, just with `bind_cols`? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Contrived as it is: `group_by(mtcars, cyl) %>% do(bind_cols(., data.frame(x=rep(mean(.$vs), nrow(.)))))`; must be the same number of rows, but can be any number of columns.

Comment: Appreciate your answers - is the `your_function` you suggest simply containing all of the calculation code?

Comment: @Qaribbean Yes! And therein lies the true difficulty...but you should be able to find many good examples of writing functions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are outputting dataframes then creating a function that performs your calculations when passed a dataframe, and outputs a dataframe will be key. In the below example the function is called `your_function()`.

For simplicity a Three stage process is used, first to create the output dataframe on the overall dataset then lapply to perform the same calculations on the sub datasets. The sub datasets are then bound together into a single dataframe before finally being combined with the output of the full dataset.

**note:** I created a new variable called "Subset" so that the outputs are all identifiable as belonging to each distinct set.

```
library(dplyr)
FullSet <- your_function(masterdata) %>% mutate(Subset = "Full")

SubSets <- lapply(unique(D1), function(n){
    masterdata %>% filter(D1 == n) %>%
      your_function(.) %>% mutate(Subset = n)
  }) %>% bind_rows()

FinalSet <- bind_rows(FullSet, SubSets)
```

if you want to run the process in parallel for speed then use

`mclapply(unique(D1), function..., mc.cores=detectCores())`

Comment: In your example above is  `MasterFunc` supposed to be the name of the first data frame?  I'm just a bit confused as to why it is assigned `<- your_function(MasterFunc)`; my assumption would've been that masterdata is entered into the function input.  Any elaboration you can offer is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Sorry it was definitely confusing hopefully this answer is clearer. I think that it worth considering which calculations are needed as if you can use summarise then @JohnSG 's answer will give a really nice solution.